# Need clarification with the following tasks

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two tasks with the following conditions:

1. Find the distance from a vector $x∈R^n$ onto a subspace $L⊂R^n$.
2. Assume that $V$ is a linear vector space with scalar product $〈·,,·〉$ and $W$ is its subspace. Find the distance from a vector $v∈V$ to $W$.

Can anybody explain to me what the principal difference between them? As far as I understand, the 2nd one is the generalized form of the 1st one. There could be things like polynomials, complex numbers, etc. If so, could you, please, provide an example of such task? Why is the existanse of scalar product here important? What would be the algorithm of finding the distance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For $x\in V$ let $x_{||}=\text{Proj}_W(x)$. If $x_{\perp}=x-x_{||}$ then the distance between $x$ and $W$ is $\|x_{\perp}\|$. If you have an orthonormal basis for $W$ the formula for $x_{||}$ is quite simple. Are you aware of this formula?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yes, I'm going through this section of la just rigth now and this reminds me of the orthogonal decomposition theorem.